# The type 'System.Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime" from TeamCity

Tags: teamcity-9.0

I'm getting the above error from our TeamCity build.

I have tried adding the following lines to the web.config.

```
<assemblies>
  <add assembly="System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /> 
</assemblies>
```

I have also installed the latest Windows SDK for .NET4.5.2.

Neither of these have resolved the error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution to this problem. I added a reference to the **System.Runtime.dll** assembly to my project. I added a reference to the following file to my project (substitute your own version of .NET in the path as necessary). You could always copy the file to your project folder and link it from there as an alternative.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades
```

This worked for me and hopefully will work for someone else.